# Share links on Linkedin not works

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

We are using share links with preview using below code

```
const onLinkedInShare = () => {
    setLinkedInModalOpen(false);
    const shareUrl = window.location.href;
    window.open(
        `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite?url=${shareUrl}`,
        '_blank',
        'width=550,height=431,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no',
    )
};
```

We are getting something went wrong page when previewing.

[image]

Also we are adding OG tags for preview supports. But still we having issue in share links in Linkedin.

```
<meta name="description" content={description} />
<meta property="og:title" content={title} />
<meta property="og:description" content={description} />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="StageClip" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content={canonicalUrl} />
<meta property="og:image" content={clip?.thumbnail} />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content={clip?.thumbnail} />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content={clip?.width?.toString()} />
<meta property="og:image:height" content={clip?.height?.toString()} />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content={title} />
<meta property="og:video" content={clip?.uri} />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content={clip?.uri} />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content={clip?.width?.toString()} />
<meta property="og:video:height" content={clip?.height?.toString()} />

<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content={canonicalUrl} />
<meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
<meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
<meta property="twitter:image" content={clip?.thumbnail} />
```

Tried on linkedin post inspector as well, it returns 500 with saying 'We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL'.

Comment: If the URL you are trying to share really has "no params", then where is the `?type=other` at the end of the URL your screenshot shows coming from? Did Linkedin _redirect_ you there before showing the error message?

Comment: Hi @CBroe ignore my variable name, I just edited the question.

Comment: I don't care what your variable is _named_, I wanted to know whether that URL you are inserting there actually does not contain any query string parameters itself. When you insert a value into the query string of a URL, that value _should_ always be properly URL-encoded - and if that value itself is a URL that contains a query string, it can even be absolutely _necessary_ to do so.

Comment: _"Tried on linkedin post inspector as well, it returns 500 with saying 'We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL'."_ - that sounds like it might be referring to a 500 error returned by _your_ system - in which case you would need to go investigate, _why_ your system responds with a 500, when LinkedIn tries to scrape your URL.